# How to use Isabelle's code_pred and values commands?

Tags: isabelle

There is an example of `code_pred` usage in "Concrete Semantics" by Tobias Nipkow and Gerwin Klein, Section 7.2.2. I've implemented a simple language based on the examples and I try to calculate values of expressions:

```
theory BooLang
  imports Main
begin

type_synonym id = string
type_synonym 'a Env = "id ⇒ 'a"

datatype BooBoolExp =
  BooLiteralExp bool |
  BooLetExp id BooBoolExp BooBoolExp |
  BooVarExp id |
  BooAndExp BooBoolExp BooBoolExp

datatype BooVal = Bv bool

type_synonym BooEnv = "BooVal Env"

inductive tbooval :: "BooBoolExp × BooEnv ⇒ BooVal ⇒ bool" (infix "⇒" 55) where
  Literal: "(BooLiteralExp b, env) ⇒ Bv b" |
  And: "⟦(a, env) ⇒ Bv av; (b, env) ⇒ Bv bv⟧ ⟹ (BooAndExp a b, env) ⇒ Bv (av ∧ bv)" |
  Var: "(BooVarExp v, env) ⇒ env v" |
  Let: "⟦(val, env) ⇒ b; (body, env(v := b)) ⇒ x⟧ ⟹ (BooLetExp v val body, env) ⇒ x"

code_pred tbooval .

values "{t. True}"

values "{t. (BooLiteralExp true, λ_. Bv false) ⇒ t}"

end
```

But for the 1st values' invocation I get the error:

> Evaluation with values is not possible because compilation with
>   code_pred was not invoked.

And for the 2nd one I get the error:

> No mode possible for comprehension {t. (BooLiteralExp true, λ_. Bv
>   false) ⇒ t}.

What's wrong with my theory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first command `values {t. True}` cannot work as this command asks Isabelle to enumerate all values of the type of `t`, which is inferred to be a type variable `'a`; and this cannot be done.

For the second command, you just misspelled `True` and `False`. As is, `true` and `false` are inferred to be boolean variables instead of boolean constants. Unlike `value`, the command `values` does not support symbolic execution in Isabelle2016-1. That is, all input arguments to the inductive  predicate must be ground values without variables. In your example, `code_pred` infers two execution modes: One in which everything is given as input and one in which only the first argument is given as input. You can see the inferred modes by passing the `[show_modes]` option as in

```
 code_pred [show_modes] tboolval .
```

You can find some further documentation on `code_pred` and `values` in the [code generator tutorial](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2016-1/doc/codegen.pdf).